# C# - Casting problems

Tags: c#, inheritance, casting

When trying to cast a class which defines a custom generic to the subclass I get an error. What did I wrong?

```
using System.Collections.Generic;

interface IStorageComponent { }

abstract class CollectionManager<T> where T : IStorageComponent { }

class Bar : IStorageComponent { }

class Foo : CollectionManager<Bar> { }

class Storage
{
    static int Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<CollectionManager<IStorageComponent>> manager = new List<CollectionManager<IStorageComponent>>
        {
            new Foo() // <-- cannot convert from 'Foo' to 'CollectionManager<IStorageComponent>'
        };
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: A `Foo` isn't a `CollectionManager<IStorageComponent>`, in the same way that a bunch of bananas isn't a `Collection<Fruit>` - you can add an apple to a `Collection<Fruit>`, but you can't add it to a bunch of bananas... (We can't tell whether that would really be a problem in your case, because `CollectionManager<T>` is empty - but it's got the potential to be a problem. C# allows generic variance to be specified for interfaces and delegates where appropriate, but not for classes.)

Comment: @JonSkeet, any reading material from your blog or msdn on the topic would be greatly helpful.

Comment: @swalker: `(IStorageComponent)new foo();` makes no sense because `Foo` is not `IStorageComponent`.

Comment: @Saravanan: Start here: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2007/10/16/covariance-and-contravariance-in-c-part-one/

Comment: @S.Walker: No, it's got nothing to do with Intellisense. `Foo` is not convertible to `<CollectionManager<IStorageComponent>`, so you can't add a `Foo` reference to a `List<CollectionManager<IStorageComponent>>`

Comment: Why is foo not convertible to `CollectionManager<IStorageComponent>` ? Foo is a `CollectionManager<Bar>` and `Bar` is an `IStorageComponent`.

Comment: @S.Walker please spend some time to read through the article and let's understand the concept than simply fixing by casting and running into issues later